# ¿Cómo imprimir un input range con React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

quería imprimir el rango de un input por pantalla, pero no sé como hacerlo.
El código sería el siguiente:

```
const Rango = () => {

const [Valor, setValor] = useState(0);

return (
    <div class="main">
        <img className ="btc" src={logo}/>
        <div className="box">
            <h1>IMPRIMIR VALOR AQUÍ</h1>
            <input type="range" className="rango"></input>
            
        </div>
     </div>

);
```

He estado intentándolo con el State que aparece arriba pero no consigo obtener el valor.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el evento `onChange` y capturar el valor del `input` y luego llamar al método `setValor` para actualizar el dicho valor.

Por ejemplo:

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [rango, setRango] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="box">
        <h1>El rango es: {rango}</h1>
        <input
          type="range"
          onChange={(ev) => setRango(ev.target.value)}
          className="rango"
        />
          </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```